# Reading a string of words into for loop from env file

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, environment-variables

I want to loop through a list of words like so:

```sh
words="hello world"
for w in $words; do
    echo $w
done
```

but I want the list of words (`words="hello world"`) to come from a `.env` file placed in a directory and then reading the env file with `export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)`.

I am able to do the above however, the for loop is only looping through the first word, as if the whitespace in `words` is stopping the loop. Why is that?

I literally copied the variable from the `.sh` script into the `.env` file and it is not working the same way.

Comment: Why not use an array? `words=(hello world); for w in "${words[@]}"; do ...; done`

Comment: You have to show how you read the file.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I did. I said I read the `.env` file with this: `export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)`

Comment: @Fravadona still did not work from `.env` file

Comment: Where does the `grep` command live? In the same script? How are you trying to assign `words` to it?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes in the same script. `words` is assigned in the `.env` file: `words="hello world"` . Then, `export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)` exports `words` so I am able to read it in the script. (but seems to be only reading `hello`)

Comment: is the `.env` file a bash script? you could just use `source .env`

Comment: Can you show the exact contents of the `.env` file? This is stil  not enough information to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solve is to separate words with comma instead of whitespace:

#### .env file

```
words=hello,world
```

#### script

Then the loop would work:

```
export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)

for w in $words; do
    echo $w
done
```